# Formulario PHP que ejecuta script en linux

Tags: php, html, html5, bash

Tengo una web en PHP que ejecuta un script para crear unos directorios y copiar unos archivos

Si ejecuto el script des de consola (ssh) me funciona correctamente pero no consigo que se ejectute desde la misma web.

Alguien me puede orientar?

Muchas gracias

**PHP**

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST["enviar"])){

    
shell_exec('wp.sh');
               
}
?>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir ../../directorio_demo
```

Comment: Probablemente sea un problema de permisos o de que esté buscando el archivo en otra ubicación.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, si que lo debe ser, he puesto como propietario a www-data y 777 (solo para probar) y no me funciona...

Sabes que mas puede ser?

Comment: Primero verifica en `php.ini` el valor de `disable_functions`. Y luego revisa los permisos del usuario del servidor web sobre el directorio. No obstante, si es para crear un directorio, mejor usa la función de PHP `mkdir()`. También considera que el directorio es relativo al script de PHP invocado, mas no al script `.sh`, revisa el valor de `getcwd()`.

Comment: ¿Te fijaste que la ruta esté bien? Podés hacer algo así `echo shell_exec("pwd");`así de paso comprobás que te permita ejecutar los comandos. Igualmente quizás sea mejor usar las funciones `mkdir` y `copy` que ya vienen con php.

Comment: Gracias por las ayudas, ahora he planteado cambiar a copy y mkdir. Solo me funciona si copio en la carpeta raiz o alguna subcarpeta pero si quiero hacer en otra ruta no me deja. he puesto como propietario a www-data y 777 (solo para probar) 

Alguna pista? Gracias